# No me muestra por consola los datos de ingreso

Tags: javascript

No me muestra por la consola los valores de ingreso, solo me muestra el DOM cargado y el evento `submit` capturado, les agradezco si lo pueden solucionar.

```js
'use strict'

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  console.log("Dom cargado");
  var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

  formulario.addEventListener("submit", function () {
    console.log("evento submit capturado");
  });
  var nombre = document.querySelector("#nombre").value;
  var apellidos = document.querySelector("#apellidos").value;
  var edad = document.querySelector("#edad").value;
  console.log(nombre, apellidos, edad);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/32-ejercicio-dom.js"></script>
        <title>Ejercicio DOM-Eventos y Funciones</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Ejercicio DOM-Eventos y Funciones</h1>
        <form action="" method="post" id="formulario" onsubmit="return false;">
            <label for="nombre" >Nombre</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"><br>

            <label for="apellidos" >Apellidos</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos"><br>
            
            <label for="edad" >Edad</label><br>
            <input type="number" name="edad" id="edad"><br>

            <input type="submit" value="enviar" id="submit" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrías agregar tu html?

Comment: @NSMichelJ si ya lo pongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resulta que cuando haces `submit`, solo estás mostrando este `console.log()`:

```
formulario.addEventListener("submit", function () {
  console.log("evento submit capturado");
});
```

Y tus variables, como están fuera, se muestran vacías porque al cargar la página, se ejecuta el listener `load`, mostrando los valores del input vacíos porque aún no los rellenaste:

```
// al cargar la página, ejecuto el listener...
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  // muestra este mensaje...
  console.log("Dom cargado");
  var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

  // esto solo se ejecuta cuando haces "submit" a tu formulario.
  formulario.addEventListener("submit", function () {
    console.log("evento submit capturado");
  });

  // luego caputra a tus valores...
  var nombre = document.querySelector("#nombre").value;
  var apellidos = document.querySelector("#apellidos").value;
  var edad = document.querySelector("#edad").value;
  // y tus valores salen vacíos porque al haber cargado la página, nunca haz rellenado los inputs
  console.log(nombre, apellidos, edad);
});
```

La solución sería capturar a los valores de tus inputs cuando hagas el `submit`, así capturará al valor que digitaste antes de que hagas el `submit`:

```
formulario.addEventListener("submit", function () {
  console.log("evento submit capturado");
  var nombre = document.querySelector("#nombre").value;
  var apellidos = document.querySelector("#apellidos").value;
  var edad = document.querySelector("#edad").value;
  console.log(nombre, apellidos, edad);
});
```

Código:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  console.log("Dom cargado");
  var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

  formulario.addEventListener("submit", function () {
    console.log("evento submit capturado");
    var nombre = document.querySelector("#nombre").value;
    var apellidos = document.querySelector("#apellidos").value;
    var edad = document.querySelector("#edad").value;
    console.log(nombre, apellidos, edad);
  });
});
```

```html
<h1>Ejercicio DOM-Eventos y Funciones</h1>
<form action="" method="post" id="formulario" onsubmit="return false;">
  <label for="nombre" >Nombre</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"><br><br>

  <label for="apellidos" >Apellidos</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos"><br><br>

  <label for="edad" >Edad</label><br>
  <input type="number" name="edad" id="edad"><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="enviar" id="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: entiendo mmmm.. muchisimas gracias, seguiré practicando y aprendiendo